# Not recieving Props from useHistory in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am designing a web app and whenever a user logs in or signs up I want the app to redirect to the home page with new Navbar.  To accomplish this, after recieving a request from axios, I am using the React useHistory method to replace the current component with the home page like this

```
  axios.post('http://localhost:3020/login', {
        email: email,
        password: password
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data);
       history.replace({
        pathname: '/',
        state: {  // location state
          login: true, 
        },
      });
      })
```

And in the App.js I am recieving the props like this

```
function check(props){
  
console.log(props);


  if(isLoggedIn === true)
  return (

    <BrowserRouter>
    <Navbars />
    <Switch>
    <Route path="/" component={Dashboard} exact />
    <Route path="/math" component={Math} />
    <Route path="/reasoning" component={Reasoning} />
    <Route path="/computer" component={Computer} />
    <Route path="/english" component={English} />
    </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
     
  )
  else
  return(

    <BrowserRouter>
    <Navbars1 />
    <Switch>
    <Route path="/" component={Home} exact />
    <Route path="/login"  render={(props) => (
      <Login {...props} isAuthed={setLoginStatus} />
    )}/>
    <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
    </Switch>
    
    
     </BrowserRouter>
  )
}
```

But props is undefined in console when I load directly and shows nothing when I redirect

Answer (score 0):

In your current setup you won't be able to do that, since

```
  <App>
    <BrowserRouter />
  </App>
```

If you change route, it won't refresh App. Instead,

```
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App>
  </BrowserRoute>
```

Do route redirect after login, and you don't need `if` statements inside App, it's taken care of by routes.

There're lots of examples, https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-set-react-router-default-route-redirect-to-home.

Comment: I did not understand sir